# Navigation Drawer Bug

Tags: bug, android-app

Type: Crash

Version: 1.0.71

Steps to reproduce:

1. Press on a site icon on the left panel (Stack Overflow for example)
2. Press on it again. The title on the action bar disappears.
3. Open the navigation drawer, and choose the same site (Stack Overflow again), it won't open.
4. While the drawer is still open, press on the user icon.
5. From the opened drawer, choose the same site as above.

Comment: Since you mentioned "on the left panel", I assumed this is on the tablet? (the interface of tablet app and phone app is different)